# SQL Query for Related Posts by Tags in Common

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

**Model**

```sql
tags
- name
- pid (short for post_id)
(fk = name + pid)

posts
- id
- title
- content
(all posts have minimum of 3 tags)
...
```

**Function**

```
create function get_related_posts(post_id uuid)
returns setof posts
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    return query
    select 
    ... (what code goes here?)  
    posts.id = $1;
end;$$;
```

Looking to create a function `get_related_posts`, which lets me get the related posts by tag.

And then I could limit those results on the front end using Supabase.

So maybe something like this, but in SQL?

**pseudocode**

```java
results = [];
Select all posts that have all 5 tags
  if any exist, add them to top of results array
loop through all possible sets of 4 tags
  select all posts that have these 4 tags
  if exists, add them to results array
loop through all possible sets of 3 tags
  select all posts that have these 3 tags
  if exists, add them to results array
loop through all possible results sets of 2 tags
  select all posts that have these 2 tags
  if exists, add them to results array
loop through all possible individual tags
  select all posts that have this one tag
  if exists, add them to the results array
return results
```

Of course, if I used paging and limit, no idea either how this would work.

Can't wrap my head around this...

J

**EDIT** - The results I am looking for are just a set of posts records...

| ID | Title | Content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | post1 title | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

J

Comment: Please post sample data and the expected results of that data, as formatted text - **no images**. See [Senseful Solutions](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) for creating formatted text. Update your questing by copy/past result between lines containing only **```**.  Even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30).

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what you mean. I have the data model clear, I do not use any images, and I clearly used three backticks to format my code. Fiddle is not relevant here, as this is an SQL question, not a website one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve problems like this step by step

The following gets all tags for a post ID

```
 select name 
 from tags
 where pid = $1
```

The following gets the tags of all posts (there will be a row per post that has a tag.

```
 select posts.id, tags.name 
 from posts
 join tags on posts.id = tags.pid
```

we can then join it to the list of tags in the original to get all items that have a matching tag

```
 select posts.id, tags.name 
 from posts
 join tags on posts.id = tags.pid
 join (
   select name 
   from tags
   where pid = $1
 ) as match on match.name = tags.name
```

we want these posts ordered by the ones with the most tags -- if we group by we can get a count of matching tags and order them.

```
 select posts.id, count(*) as match_count 
 from posts
 join tags on posts.id = tags.pid
 join (
   select name 
   from tags
   where pid = $1
 ) as match on match.name = tags.name
 group by post.id
 order by match_count desc
```

A quick note on thinking like sql -- sql works in sets -- this means you don't use if statements (like your code) but instead filters or joins.  As you can see each step I performed was over an entire set of data -- not looking at row by row.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Still need to work on my "thinking" in SQL for sure :)

Comment: @Jonathan -- you're welcome.  You will get it -- just break problems down, try it out and see the results.